# querySelector to get specific node value with ng-if property

Tags: javascript, html

I was searching javascript code to get the content of HTML tag having attribute name ng-if="desc.description" using javascript querySelectors.

```
<li ng-bind-html="esc.description" ng-if="desc.description">Hello world.</li>
```

Comment: What problem did you encounter, what's the question you're asking?

Comment: I was writing a javascript code to get the content of the attribute from the rendered webpage.

Answer (score 2):

Use an attribute selector.

```
var contents = document.querySelector("[ng-if='desc.description']").innerHTML
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `getAttribute()` method

Your Element

```
<script>
var a = document.getElementById('hey')
var x = a.getAttribute('ng-if') // "/"

alert(x);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define Id value.

HTML:

```
<li id="id-ex" ng-bind-html="esc.description" ng-if="desc.description">Hello world.</li>
```

JS:

```
var myInnerHtml = document.getElementById("id-ex").innerHTML;
```